# MVC 3 EF basic architecture question

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm an MVC / EF newb.

I've got a few different tables I want in my database: say lemons, sugar, and water.

Should I create three separate models: lemons, sugar, and water or make one big model that defines three different classes (with three separate DBContext classes?) and then scaffold each model?

Right now I'm making separate models, but it looks like I have to end up making three separate databases which seems overkill.

The movie example only has one table, so it doesn't answer my question very well.

Comment: need more details. Are you tryin to do code or model first or database first? Try starting with datbase first. What movie? What does MVC have to do with this?

Comment: yes, more clarification please--three separate databases? did you mean models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have 3 model classes (one for each of your entities)

```
public class Lemon
{
}

public class Sugar
{
}

public class Water
{
}
```

and create one DbContext for them:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Lemon> LemonSet
    public DbSet<Sugar> SugarSet
    public DbSet<Water> WaterSet
}
```

This way, you'll be using EF Code First with 3 model classes and one database

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oops. So what I've done is I have a Lemon.cs, a Sugar.cs, and a Water.cs file each with their own class that derives from DbContext. Is it worth starting over or does it even matter? So far I can do everything I want, but I'm wondering if it will spell a lot of extra work in the future. I'm guessing I can still do the scaffolding if the DbSets are all defined in the same class ... Would you redo it?

Comment: The `DbContext` kind of represents your database, which means that you ought to have only one. With EF Code First, entities (models) should be POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects, meaning: simple classes). So, the answer would be, yeah, I would certainly redo it ;)